# ASP.Net open source sample E-commerce project implemented with DDD

Tags: open-source, domain-driven-design, e-commerce

I am starting to build a E-commerce site in ASP.Net webform and KnockoutJS. I'm also preferring to use EF6 and DDD implementation. Is there any open source E-commerce sample solution which is also implemented DDD methodology.

Comment: Even if it were one, it would be useless to you since you get to see the result but not the design process, the reasons behind the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are open source E-commerce, however its a ASP.NET MVC applications, not WebForm - [nopCommerce](https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/) 
Though I wouldn't call it a sample application. But its good for study.